# Monotonicity of $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2+y^2}{x+y}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2+y^2}{x+y} $ where $x,y \in [0,1]$

let $x\leq r$ and $y\leq s$ I have to prove\disprove $f(x,y)\leq f(r,s)$.

Clearly $x^2+y^2\leq r^2+s^2$ and $x+y\leq r+s$ but then $\frac{1}{x+y}\geq \frac{1}{r+s}$ ??

Comment: No.  We can define partial order on $[0,1]^2$

Answer (score 1):

It is not true.

As one of many counterexamples, consider $x=r=1$ and $y=0, s=\frac12$

Then $\dfrac{1^2+0^2}{1+0}=1 \gt \dfrac56 = \dfrac{1^2+\left(\frac12\right)^2}{1+\frac12}$ so $f(x,y) \not \le f(r,s)$ even though $x \le r$ and $y \le s$

Answer (score 1):

The claim is not true, however a slightly modified claim is (see (2) below).

1) The claim is not true, here is a counterexample.

Let $r = 0.25$ and $s = 0.5$. Then $f(r,s) = \frac{0.25^2+0.5^2}{0.75} = \frac{5}{12} \simeq 0.4167 $.

Now select $x = 0.01 < r$ and $y = 0.49 <s$. We have

$f(x,y)=\frac{0.01^2+0.49^2}{0.5} \simeq  0.4804 > f(r,s)$.

2) The claim is true for $r=s$. (Check it!)